# ListViewAnimations NoClassDefFound error

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am using `ListViewAnimations` core library version 3.1.0 in my android application. I have only included `lib-core` library as per the [setup instructions](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations). But unfortunately I am receiving following error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: [Lcom/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator;
11-23 14:47:18.489 14928-14928/com.gi.giml E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.appearance.AnimationAdapter.animateViewIfNecessary(AnimationAdapter.java:174)
11-23 14:47:18.489 14928-14928/com.gi.giml E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.appearance.AnimationAdapter.getView(AnimationAdapter.java:145)
11-23 14:47:18.489 14928-14928/com.gi.giml E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
11-23 14:47:18.489 14928-14928/com.gi.giml E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1875)
11-23 14:47:18.489 14928-14928/com.gi.giml E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
11-23 14:47:18.489 14928-14928/com.gi.giml E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
11-23 14:47:18.489 14928-14928/com.gi.giml E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1684)
11-23 14:47:18.489 14928-14928/com.gi.giml E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
11-23 14:47:18.489 14928-14928/com.gi.giml E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
11-23 14:47:18.489 14928-14928/com.gi.giml E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
11-23 14:47:18.489 14928-14928/com.gi.giml E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
```

I am using this animation library in my app like below:

```
ListView lv = new ListView(getActivity());

SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter bottomInAnimationAdapter = new SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.subgroup_list_layout, R.id.textView, result));
bottomInAnimationAdapter.setAbsListView(lv);
lv.setAdapter(bottomInAnimationAdapter);
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: have you added NineOldAndroids.jar also ?

Comment: @DroidDev Actually I am testing it on Android 6.0 and according to the instructions given on that page I don't think it requires that library on latest Android version.

Comment: Ok but can you try one time by adding that jar and let me know.

Comment: @DroidDev I think I should switch to native Animation API that comes with SDK 14 and above and implement the custom animation instead of using this old library.

Answer (score 0):

`ListViewAnimations` is based on `NineOldAndroids` and several classes reference `com.nineoldandroids.animation.Animator` directly. So you need to include this library as well.

If you're using gradle, this is done automatically by only declaring

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0@aar'
}
```

in your *build.gradle*. The same holds if you're using Maven and *pom.xml*. Otherwise you need to follow the instructions on the page you linked yourself:

> - Download the jar files you need: (`lib-core`)
> - Download the latest *NineOldAndroids.jar* file
> - Add the *.jar* files to your project's `libs` folder, or add them as external jars to your project's build path.

Answer (score 0):

You should also include "nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar" file in your project along with `dependencies {
compile 'com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:3.1.0@aar'
}`
add jar file to the lib folder and add this line in dependency 
`compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')` it works fine for this error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: [Lcom/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator;"

link to download jar file https://github.com/downloads/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar